# SIGTSTP isn't caught by child processes

Tags: c, shell, signals, jobs, keyboardinterrupt

I am working on a shell project in C, and more specifically on the job control aspect of it. I am on the late testing bits and here is what is happening to me :

I am creating foreground jobs that I want to stop thanks to ctrl-Z (or to interrupt with Ctrl-C ; I get exactly the same behaviour) and I am testing this behaviour on long commands such as "ls -R /".

The first time I suspend the job works just fine : I get my input back, I see the suspended job in my job list, etc..

Then, I try launching a second "ls -R /" (with the first one still stopped), but this time I can't stop it ; And I can't seem to know why...

The job is in the foreground of the terminal (checked with the "ps -o state" command), it catches the SIGTSTP signal if I hard code a kill(SIGTSTP) in the parent shell (but it doesn't catch a "kill -TSTP [pid_of_child]" command sent from another shell), I can see the Ctrl-Z I am typing in my terminal when I do, but it just wont stop. It seems like the first ls call toggles something that blocks the signal handlers.

It also seems like this behaviour may happen after a random number of calls to "ls -R /" (its not always the second call that is unstoppable, though it often is).

For obvious reasons I am not posting all of the code of 42sh here. Alltough here are a few bits :

```
void                    ft_set_child_signal(int shell_pid)
{

sigset_t                wakeup_sig;
struct sigaction        action;

ft_bzero(&action, sizeof(sigaction));
action.sa_handler = &ft_catch_sigusr1;
sigaction(SIGUSR1, &action, NULL);

sigfillset(&wakeup_sig); // is here for synchronicity of multi-process jobs.
sigdelset(&wakeup_sig, SIGUSR1); //same
kill(shell_pid, SIGUSR1); //same
sigsuspend(&wakeup_sig); //same
signal(SIGCONT, SIG_DFL);
signal(SIGINT, SIG_DFL);
signal(SIGQUIT, SIG_DFL);
signal(SIGTSTP, SIG_DFL); // is reset to default in child while SIG_IGN in parent
signal(SIGTTIN, SIG_DFL);
signal(SIGTTOU, SIG_DFL);
signal(SIGUSR1, SIG_IGN);
signal(SIGUSR2, SIG_IGN);
}
```

Of course, after that ft_set_child_signal function, I will call execve (which might reset the behaviour of signals ? Or so I read). I made sure all child process are fork from the shell directly. This is how I wait for childs in the parent:

```
int             ft_wait_foreground(t_job* job)
{
sigset_t        wakeup_sig;

tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, job->pgid);
sigfillset(&wakeup_sig);
sigdelset(&wakeup_sig, SIGCHLD);
killpg(job->pgid, SIGUSR1);
ft_dprintf(2, "Job in foreground: %i\n", tcgetpgrp(0));
while (ISRUNNING(job->status))
        sigsuspend(&wakeup_sig);
tcsetpgrp(STDIN_FILENO, getpid());
if (WIFSTOPPED(job->status))
        return (job->status);
return (((t_process*)(job->process->content))->status);
}

void            ft_sigchld_handler(int nbr)
{
int                     ret_status;
int                     pid;
t_job           *job;
t_process       *process;

(void)nbr;
while ((pid = waitpid(-1, &ret_status, WUNTRACED | WNOHANG)) > 0)
{
ft_dprintf(2, "handler: wait caught pid: %i\n", pid);
        if ((job = ft_get_job_pgid(pid)))
        {
                job->status = ret_status | (BACKGROUND &job->status);
                process = ft_get_process_from_job(job, pid);
        }
        else if (!(process = ft_get_process_pid(pid)))
                continue ;
        ft_dprintf(2, "handler: process updated: %i\n", ret_status);
        process->status = ret_status;
}
ft_update_job_status();
}
```

If you see any errors or have any idea concerning my problem, let me know (I am also taking any advice :)

Comment: The wierdest part is that it seems to come specifically from "ls -R /": I can launch 10 times the "yes" command and stop it without any problem but as soon as ls comes around, any subsequent yes it unstoppable.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't touched C for 3 years, but I made the same shell project and in mine there is no problem you are dealing with. Maybe the working implementation will give you an idea, maybe it won't. If you're brave enough to dig into someone's else code, you're welcome [here](https://github.com/artem-bondar/system-operating-shell).